# How to remove overnight returns from intraday data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, finance, quantitative-finance

I have a Pandas DataFrame with intraday price data (volume weighted, aggregated by minute) spanning several months.

```
In[1]: VWAPData
Out[93]: 
Prices
2014-02-03 09:30:00    10.450000
2014-02-03 11:04:00    10.450000
2014-02-03 12:28:00    10.326600
2014-02-03 13:31:00    10.290000
2014-02-03 13:44:00    10.326500
...
2014-07-31 13:08:00    15.8500
2014-07-31 13:10:00    15.8600
2014-07-31 13:44:00    15.8600
2014-07-31 15:44:00    15.9101
2014-07-31 15:58:00    15.9300
```

As you can see, some minutes have no data (due to no trading).

I would like to calculate the returns between each data point, *ignoring overnight returns*.  I can't assume the first trade happens at the same time each day.  How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by returns? The difference of prices between one entry and the next one? Or the percent difference?

If that's the case (I'll do the difference between prices), I can think of a iterative method. Someone might have a better one. Let 'df' be your dataframe name, 'Time' be the field that stores the time of entry, and 'Price' be the field with the price. Also that 'Time' store datetime types

```
df['Return'] = np.NaN
for i in xrange(len(df)):
    if i ==0: break
    if df['Time'].iat[i].day == df['Time'].iat[i-1].day:
        df['Return'].iat[i] = df['Price'].iat[i] - df['Price'].iat[i-1]
```

That way you avoid doing overnight returns. Just check if it's intraday (the day is the same)